# How to suffix all properties with !important

Tags: stylus

I want to suffix all my rules with `!important`, how can I do this with stylus?

like I have

```
body
   width 100%
   color #fff
   ...
```

and I want this as output:

```
body {
   width: 100% !important;
   color: #fff !important;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

afaik stylus does'nt have built in functionality to do something like this.
I think you could achieve what you want with some simple regex maybe you should look [here for some advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html),
although I don't recommend overusing `!important`.

[Some advice on `!important` usage](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: Hi, I know it sounds crazy, to use important, but when working with something like [cleanslate](https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate) there's no other way. I know why do I use..., but that's an another question.

Comment: Hey, you could also use some jQuery, [this plugin](https://github.com/premasagar/important)
is created by the same guy who created cleanslate, and perfectly fits the problem mentioned in the question.
just use this one line of javascript and all you styles will be `!important`

`jQuery.important();`

Answer (score 0):

It is a task better suited for something like PostCSS, but you can do this in Stylus too, but you'll need to list all the properties you'd like to override:

```
make_important()
  {called-from}: arguments (!important in arguments ? unquote('') : !important)

// List all the properties you'd like to override

props = background, width, height, padding-left, margin-left, color, margin-bottom, font-size, border-left, font, opacity, transition, display, padding-bottom, margin-top, border, background-position, margin, padding

for prop in props
  define(''+prop, @(){
    make_important(arguments)
  })
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/lopora/edit?css,output

Comment: It sounds promising, however doesn't work all cases, example if you have a property value which is also a property name, like *right*, than it will end like this: http://jsbin.com/cedebawuli/1

Comment: Yep, while it still could be somewhat fixed, the best shot would be still to use PostCSS instead.